# Maximum number of bind parameters in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I have a question about the maximum number of bind parameters that can be passed to a query I wish to execute using SQLAlchemy.

My query is a set of SELECT statements all grouped together via UNION (about 100+)
and each select statement will be passed a different value. The reason why I need to do this via a UNION is that I am using the trigram matching operator % in Postgres (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/pgtrgm.html) so I can't combine the statements into one using IN.

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM TABLE where col3=:p1 AND col2 % :q1
UNION 
SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM TABLE where col3=:p2 AND col2 % :q2
UNION 
SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM TABLE where col3=:p3 AND col2 % :q3
UNION 
...
```

etc. 
Is there a limit that would cause it to fail ?
where the params are `(p1,q1, p2,q2, p3, q3)` etc.

Comment: Can't you use VALUES and `similarity`?

Comment: I'm not sure how I'd express the above SQL with just VALUES and similarity. Can you give an example ?

Comment: I'm not that sure and can't test right now, but I think something like: `select col1, col2, col3, temp from table t, VALUES p1, p2, p3, ... where col3 = temp AND col2 % p1`. (Actually that looks syntactly incorrect, but the logic should be alright)

Comment: But I still wish to do similarity checks for multiple input strings q1, q2, q3 etc.

Comment: Yes sorry I meant `p, q from table t, VALUES (p1, q1), ...` or did I misunderstand your problem?

Comment: Ok, I get it - something like `SELECT a.col1, a.col2, t.col1 FROM table a, (VALUES('x1','x2'),('y1','y2'),('z1','z2')) as t(col1,col2) WHERE a.col2=col2 AND a.col1 % t.col1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to achieve my goal by using a VALUES list in Postgresql:

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM TABLE a,  
VALUES(('x1','x2','x3'), ('y1','y2','y3'), ('z1','z2','z3')) 
AS t(col1, col2, col3) 
WHERE a.col1=t.col1 AND lower(a.col2) % t.name
```